# Need to use the right Regex format to pass build using Console Output(parsed) in Jenkins

Tags: java, regex, jenkins, regex-negation

I have to parse to this particular output :
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "setup.exe -f properties_2021.1.1"

I am not able to get the right regex in conf file. My regex looks like this:

```
ok /\"cmd"\: \"setup\.exe \-f properties\_/
```

Comment: Did you miss a ` \\`
Try `/\"cmd\"\: \"setup\.exe \-f properties\_/`

Comment: Tried still same issue.

Comment: Whether you use regular expressions in Jenkins files

Comment: Its working now. I had missed the quotes. Thanks.